# post and pre increment not working as expected for REPL variable in scala

Tags: java, scala, compiler-errors, integer, post-increment

I know that there is no `++` and `--` in scala instead I have to use `+=` and `-=`

But when I try

```
scala> var a=2
a: Int = 2

scala> a +=1

scala> a
res11: Int = 3
```

the above works fine but not the below one

```
scala> 5
res13: Int = 5

scala> res13 +=1
<console>:9: error: value += is not a member of Int
              res13 +=1
                    ^
```

The type of both variable `a` and `res13` is `Int` but the second case is not working as the first case.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I don't know about Scala.  But I think `res13` represents an integer value, not an integer variable.  So `5 += 1` is error.

Comment: thanks for the reply @saka1029 but is there any way I can confirm this through REPL console

Comment: @downvoter can you explain what is wrong in my question?

Comment: `res13 = 6` will be error too.

Comment: Such variable usage is not idiomatic/recommanded in Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: you declared `a` a `var`, meaning its value can be changed. On the other hand, the REPL `res<x>` are read-only `val`s, so they can't be changed.

Now, to the error message. In Scala, `Int`s are not special at language level, and neither are operators. So `a += 1` means `a.+=(1)` where `+=` is the method name. And indeed, there is no `+=` method on `Int`, which is the error message that you get. But when the operator name ends with "=" and cannot be found, **IF** the receiver is a `var`, then the compiler will transform `a op= b` into `a = a op b`. So in the first case, `a += 1` becomes `a = a + 1`. This works, as `+` is of course available on `Int`, but doesn't in the second case.

The error message is a bit misleading. It should probably say that there is no `+=` member, but, as there is a `+` member, it should also say that `res13` can't be assigned to.

Comment: To add to this answer, scala automatically  undefined  expressions with immutable  types. While mutable variables most be explicitly  declared

Answer (score 1):

`res13` is a `val` (the definition would look like `val res13 = 5`), not a `var`. Vals are "values", they cannot be modified, so operators like `+=` and `-=` don't work with them.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but is there any way I can confirm this through REPL console

Comment: To add to this answer, scala automatically set undefined expressions with immutable data types. While mutable variables most be explicitly declared

Answer (score 0):

The desugaring for operators which look like `ω=`, where `ω` is a string of operator characters is a bit different from other operators.

Whereas

```
a foo b
```

is equivalent to

```
a.foo(b)
```

in the case of

```
a ω= b
```

this is only equivalent to

```
a.ω=(b)
```

if it typechecks, otherwise, the compiler will also try

```
a = a ω b
```

(with the added provision that `a` is guaranteed to only be evaluated once) i.e.

```
a = a.ω(b)
```

or

```
this.a_=(a.ω(b))
```

So, in your case, since `Int` is immutable, and there is no `Int.+=` method, the code will actually desugar to

```
a = a.+(1) // *not* a.+=(1)
```

and

```
res13 = res13.+(1) // *not* res13.+=(1)
```

which works in the first case, because `a` is a `var` and thus `a = foo` is legal, whereas in the second case, `res13` is a `val` (it represents the 13th evaluation result of your REPL session, it would be *extremely* weird if that all of a sudden changes!) and thus assignment is not legal.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about what you can show from console:

You can use the magic suffix `// show` to see what is generated.

After the fact, you can get the symbol and type of an identifier, both user-defined and synthetic.

```
scala> 42 // show
object $read extends scala.AnyRef {
  def <init>() = {
    super.<init>;
    ()
  };
  object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>;
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>() = {
        super.<init>;
        ()
      };
      val res0 = 42
    }
  }
}
res0: Int = 42

scala> $intp.symbolOfIdent("res0").owner.typeSignature
res1: $intp.global.Type =
Object {
  def <init>(): type
  val res0(): Int
  private[this] val res0: Int
}
```

That shows both the underlying field and the accessor. Compare with a var:

```
scala> var a = 7
a: Int = 7

scala> $intp.symbolOfIdent("a").owner.typeSignature
res4: $intp.global.Type =
Object {
  def <init>(): type
  def a(): Int
  def a_=(x$1: Int): Unit
  private[this] var a: Int
}
```

There is other available API such as

```
$intp.typeOfTerm("res0").resultType.typeSymbol.typeSignature
```

or

```
scala> val m = collection.mutable.Map(1->2)
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> $intp.typeOfTerm("m").resultType member $intp.global.TermName("+=").encodedName
res7: $intp.global.Symbol = value +=
```

where

```
scala> $intp.global.TermName("+=").encodedName
res8: $intp.global.TermName = $plus$eq
```